# Storing Data and Instructions in Memory

Tags: intel-fpga, risc

I have implemented a **RiscV32 single cycle processor using Verilog**. Now I am trying to upload it to a FPGA (DE2 - 115 board) and check the functioning. But how do I store instructions and data in the memory block? Is there way to store instructions and data in memory block using **UART** protocol?

I found out that we can initialize the memory block with initial data. But how do store instructions and data while the FPGA is powered up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add functionality to an FPGA design, like putting bytes received through an UART into memory blocks, *you will have to add that functionality to your design*. The FPGA only does what you define it to do!

So, if you want an UART receiver to fill memories, you will need to find an existing UART IP core, instantiate it, and make it interact with the memory. The easiest way of course would be making that UART core available to the RISC-V core as peripheral - so that for example a software boatloader that is the initial program stored at FPGA configuration time can receive data via UART, put it in RAM at the desired addresses, and finally jump to it.